# is there a better or more elegant way to handling dictionary loop exception in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, exception

basically I'm just parsing a JSON file containing informations about several movies and save some of them in a different dictionary for later use

example:
not all movies have a description, I'm using a try/except to handle the "keyError" that appears when there is no description in the json, is there a better way to do it?

```py
for movie in json:
    # other entries
    try:
        description = {"description": movie_details['Description']}
    except KeyError:
        description = {"description": ""}
    # other entries
    try:
        other_value = {"other_value": movie_details["other_value"]
    except KeyError:
        other_value = {"other_value": ""}
```

this seems to me very "dirty", if you have some tip to write a cleaner code would be awesome

Thanks

Comment: You could use .get, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)

Comment: if `movie_details` is a `dict` you can ask before accessing `'value' in movie_details`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `.get()` with sentinal value:

```
for movie in json:
    description = {'description': movie_details.get('Description', '')}
    # and similarly for other values...
```

This makes sure that if the key is not found, the sentinal value is used.

I'm not that sure if you needed to use `movie_details` or `movie` inside the loop. I think you meant the latter.

Answer (score 1):

one way is to convert `movie_details` to a `collections.defaultdict`

```
movie_details = collections.defaultdict(str,movie_details)
```

if a key is not found, the specialized dictionary object calls `str` to create a new key (empty string)

Once you've done this, just use it like a normal dict access:

```
description = {'description': movie_details['Description']}
```